# Redirect Scheme to https and continue to Path Rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We have a few path-based rewrite rules in our `.htaccess` file. For example if the URI points to `/foobar/somestring` redirect to `/foo/somestring` page, but we also want to force loading the resource over `https`.

We could include `https://%{HTTP_HOST}` in all of the `RewriteRule`s, with the more specific URIs addressed first, but I'm pretty sure that shouldn't be necessary.

I have looked through the [apache flags docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html), but am having trouble find a way to tell the server to address the `scheme` in one way and continue reading rules and conditions to address `paths`.

This is the long-handed approach we have now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/foo
  # Long list
  RewriteRule ^foobar/(bat.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/foo/$1 [L,R=301]
  RewriteRule ^foobar/(bas.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/foo/$1 [L,R=301]
  # URI not found
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php [L]
  # And finally
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks much.

Comment: This is a messy task for Apache. Personally, I'd hard-code the `https` for simplicity and be done with it.  Also I'd put all the https redirect logic before the 404 routing logic so users don't wind up seeing index.php directly in their browser. Please use 302 redirects when testing this sort of stuff so you don't wind up with cached 301s in your browser and overlook these sort of things. To achieve this, use normal rewrites first then only issue a redirect at the bottom. The skip flag, or getting/setting ENV variables, or comparing the current URI to the REQUEST_URI can all achieve this.

Comment: There actually is no real need to combine the two things. You implement the redirection to the `https` protocol by itself. Reason is 1. that this has to be done only once for any client, regardless of how many requests they send and 2. that the rewriting is done _in a different host_ inside your http server.

Comment: @Ultimater what do you mean by "hard-code the `https` for simplicity"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue here is understanding [the difference between a Redirect and a ReWrite](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/rewrite-vs-redirect-what-s-the-difference). In short, a Redirect happens on the Client Side, changing the URL in the browser. A Rewrite happens on the Server Side and is transparent to the browser/client.

- An example of a Redirect would be changing the protocol from `http://` to `https://` or adding or removing the `www` subdomain.
- An example of a Rewrite would be receiving a path like `/foo-bar-bas` and, before sending it to be handled by the server (via ASP, Python, php, ruby on rails, node.js, etc), rewriting it as `article.aspx?name=foo_bar_bar` or some such.

You can see in the OP above, the Redirect from `http://` to `https://`, when it was at the top of the rule block, was short-circuiting the Rewrites below it because of the following two flags:

- `R=301` which tells the browser, "this (A) resource has moved, it's now at this (B) location"
- `L` which tells Apache, "stop processing the rule set".
- The third flag, `NC` means to ignore case, and `/?(.*)` is case insensitive anyway.

All that's needed is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/foobar
  RewriteRule ^foobar/(bat.*)$ /foo/$1 [L,R=301]
  RewriteRule ^foobar/(bas.*)$ /foo/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Part of what's confusing is that we're using a "Rewrite" rule to achieve the "Redirection" (as well as the rewrites below it.) Apache also supports a [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive outside of the `mod_rewrite` module. I'm not sure if that would work here.

It's worth restating @Ultimater's comment from above that *when testing*, using the [302](https://http.cat/302) *found* status code as opposed to the [301](https://http.cat/301) *moved permanently* status code with the `R` flag will prevent sending the wrong message out to web crawlers or (potentially your own) browsers.